# Prove that a function $\ln (e^{a_1} + e^{a_2} + \cdots + e^{a_n} )$ is convex?

Tags: convex

Define the function:

$$f(a_1, a_2, · · · , a_n) = \ln (e^{a_1} + e^{a_2} + \cdots + e^{a_n} ).$$

I want to prove that $f$ is convex.  Now, to show that is a function is convex, we can take second derivative of the function and if it is greater than zero then the function is convex.  But here second derivative would be negative, if I am not wrong.  Alternatively, $f$ is convex if and only if the Hessian matrix $Hf(x)$ is positive semi-definite for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  How do I do the proof?

Comment: Not all second derivatives are negative.  Note that matrices with negative values (off the diagonal) can be positive-semidefinite.  Why not work out the derivatives in the case $n=2$ and maybe the case $n=3$ to see what is going on?

Comment: if we calculate hesian matrix, it would be a symmetric matrix with all diagonal value -ve, would it be positive semidefinite?

Comment: You must be miscalculating: all diagonal elements are positive.

Comment: okay, I was calculating first derivative, once we calculate second derivative all values will be positive, thanks.

Comment: How do we prove then that the matrix is semi-definite?

Comment: There are various ways to do that, ranging from applying the definition to using Sylvester's Criterion to computing (or estimating) the smallest eigenvalue to exploiting clever ways of expressing the matrix (I think I can do it that way).  Maybe an induction on $n$ would work.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines z(transpose) . H . Z >=0 

would it be a good idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function you are looking at is the [LogSumExp function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp):

$$f(\mathbf{a}) = \ln \Big( \sum_{i=1}^n \exp(a_i) \Big)
\quad \quad \quad
\text{for all } \mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

Its gradient vector and Hessian matrix are given respectively by:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\nabla f(\mathbf{a}) 
&= \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(a_i)} (\exp(a_1),...,\exp(a_n)), \\[12pt]
\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{a}) 
&= \text{diag}(\nabla f(\mathbf{a})) - \nabla f(\mathbf{a}) \nabla f(\mathbf{a})^\text{T}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

(Here we have written the Hessian matrix in terms of the gradient vector.  This is useful for the next step.)  For any $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have the quadratic form:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbf{z}^\text{T} (\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{a})) \mathbf{z} 
&= \mathbf{z}^\text{T} \Big[ \text{diag}(\nabla f(\mathbf{a})) - \nabla f(\mathbf{a}) \nabla f(\mathbf{a})^\text{T} \Big] \mathbf{z} \\[6pt]
&= \mathbf{z}^\text{T} \text{diag}(\nabla f(\mathbf{a})) \mathbf{z} 
- \mathbf{z}^\text{T} \nabla f(\mathbf{a}) \nabla f(\mathbf{a})^\text{T} \mathbf{z} \\[6pt]
&= \mathbf{z}^\text{T} \text{diag}(\nabla f(\mathbf{a})) \mathbf{z} 
- (\nabla f(\mathbf{a}) \cdot \mathbf{z})^\text{T} (\nabla f(\mathbf{a}) \cdot \mathbf{z}) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbf{z}^\text{T} \text{diag}(\nabla f(\mathbf{a})) \mathbf{z} 
- || \nabla f(\mathbf{a}) \cdot \mathbf{z} ||^2 \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \bigg( \frac{\exp(a_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(a_i)} \bigg) z_i^2 
- \sum_{i=1}^n \bigg( \frac{\exp(a_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(a_i)} \bigg)^2 z_i^2 \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(a_i)} \sum_{i=1}^n \exp(a_i) z_i^2 \Bigg[ 1 - \frac{\exp(a_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(a_i)} \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \neq i} \exp(a_i) \exp(a_j) z_i^2}{(\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(a_i))^2} \geqslant 0. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This establishes that the Hessian matrix is non-negative definite, which means that the LogSumExp function is (weakly) convex.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189638/about-the-strictly-convexity-of-log-sum-exp-function  for some more details.